# Dynamic CRM Malicious File Upload

Tags: dynamics-crm

We have built an asp.net web application (portal) to create records in Dynamic CRM Online instance. The webform has several file upload controls, Does microsoft crm online scan them for viruses automatically before uploading? Right now I am able to upload malicious files.
Any links that suggest how microsoft handles malicious file uploads are welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Attachments saved to Dynamics CRM Online are not virus scanned.

If you are receiving files from the public and saving them to Dynamics CRM you are responsible for checking the contents of those files as part of the submission portal you have developed.